# Registering Speakers

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

UPDATE: `lsusb` results: https://pastebin.com/37tUifWb

A 16.04 laptop features speakers and a headphone port.  I would like to use the speakers, however, I am unable to select them:

[image]

What commands can be issued to prompt the operating system to search & find the speakers?  It would be nice if the audio would automatically toggle between the headphone port and speaker.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? what exact hardware are we talking about (model number), what kernel version, pulseaudio version? `lsusb -v` would be a good place to start as the first item in the list is usually the realtek card and it says how many ouputs it has (for example front and back jack) : `bNumEndpoints           2`

Comment: @tatsu  Good questions / comments.  16.04 on HP8440p laptop: `lsusb` link provided in OP.  Thank you